# docker container runtime application configurations

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-java

We have a java application. It connects to the oracle database. It has three properties files and the customer changes value of those properties files when we deployed our application to the customer site. We have another python script that allows customer to modify those properties files and start the main app after configuration is done.

Now we want to containerized our java app and want to use swarm mode. the only problem is to find the easy way for customer to edit those properties files before I start the container.

Any ideas docker Gurus ?

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Move to the config to something external. Either environment variables or better still something like consul or etcd.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We are shipping docker image in a tar file and two configuration files. And customer will edit config1.properties and config2.properties file then these edited two files need to be inside of the tar file so that they can use docker load -i image1.tar to load the image.

Comment: This is how you're deploying to someone who's paying you money? :p

Comment: not yet :) we are trying to give customer best way to modify config files. We examining different options available with less maintenance.

Comment: What about confd?
http://www.mricho.com/confd-and-docker-separating-config-and-code-for-containers/